# WebSocket Server Data Framing (RFC6455)

Tags: perl, websocket

I have a problem. When I want to achieve WebSocket server, the server can't send data to the client (in Chrome 16). For example, sending the text "Hello", the server sends the data framing "0x81 0x05 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f" to the client, but the browser can't receive the data. Is this code wrong?

```
sub getSendDataNoMask{
    my $dataStr="Hello";
    my @ret;

    push(@ret,pack("H*","81"));
    push(@ret,pack("H*","05"));
    push(@ret,$dataStr);

    return join("",@ret);
}
```

Comment: You need to say how you are sending the data -- what are you doing with the return value of `getSendDataNoMask`?

Comment: the return value is socket sending data,like this, $socket->send(getSendDataNoMask()); just this data,not any more....

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get from the Chrome Javascript console?

You also didn't post your handshake code (the more likely thing to have a problem). Are you certain that the handshake was completed successfully? In other words, did you get an onopen event in the browser?

```
var ws = WebSocket("ws://myhost:6080/websocket");
ws.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("connection opened");
};
ws.onmessage
    console.log("Got data: " + e.data);
};
```

If you didn't get an opopen event then the handshake never finished successfully. If you are getting on onopen event, then I would try sending data the opposite direction and make sure you can receive and decode frames from your perl server before trying to send.

Comment: @Random, thanks for the code, but can you answer my questions too. I'm too busy at the moment to test your code for you.

Comment: 1.Are you certain that the handshake was completed successfully?(Yes)

Comment: 2.did you get an onopen event in the browser?(Yes)

Comment: I can received the data from browser,but can't send data to it which like the example code.